# Archimedes Law (Archimedes' principle)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics

I am struggling with understand the whole situation that is described in the following question:
Two balls attached to a string that connects with the same volume of 15 ${cm}^3$. They float on the water(fresh water) when only one half of the top ball is in the water and the other one is floating above water level. The mass of the bottom ball is 4 times the mass of the top ball.
I need to find the mass of each ball.

[image]

Thanks to everyone who will answer and guide towards the needed answer.

Comment: Can you provide the original statement?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand what original statement

Comment: It would appear from your diagram that the bottom ball is fully submerged under water.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't been clear, that the 2nd ball is fully submerged under water

Comment: My hint: draw a free body diagram of the two connected spheres.  That FBD should show a weight of the spheres and a buoyant force that equals that weight, from which you can solve for the mass of each sphere.

Comment: @Anton Toha , I am having trouble visualising the question. Are you sure what you have posted matches with your source? There surely something wrong in the second line.

Comment: @AlphaDelta it's a translation from Hebrew to English. I'll try to re-write the question. Here it is: Two balls with the same volume of 15 ${cm}^3$ tied between themselves with a rope. They float as described in the picture, while only half of the top ball is in the water(the ball that is on the bottom is fully in the water). They are in an even state - not moving. The mass of the bottom ball, is 4 times the mass of the top ball. Does that makes more sense?

Comment: Draw separate free body diagrams. For top ball, there is buoyant force(up), weight(down) and tension(down). For second ball, bouyant force(up), tension(up) and weight(down). Tension is of-course same in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buoyant force $F_b$ is given by
$$
F_b = -\rho gV
$$
$\rho$: fluid density 
$g$: gravitational acceleration 
$V$: volume of displaced fluid

The volume of water displaced is equal to the volume occupied by the submerged portions of the two spheres; $\rho$ and $g$ are constants that can be looked up. Knowing this, we can determine $F_b$ and construct a free body diagram of the system of two spheres, with $F_b$ and $F_g$ (gravitational force) acting on the system in opposite directions. The rest is a bit of algebra involving Newton's Second Law $F=ma$ and taking $m_{bottom\_sphere} = 4m_{top\_sphere}$. Hope this helps!

Comment: N this case, a, is zero.  If we assume that the bottom ball is submerged, then: 5mg – ρg(1.5)V = 0 where m and V refer to the upper ball.